# android R.layout concept

Tags: android, layout, android-widget

can I genrate java code instead using xml code ?
 lets say i want to do this xml code in a loop :

```
<TableRow 
 android:id="@+id/LivingCreture"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView android:text="LivingCreture" 
 android:gravity="left"
 android:id="@+id/LivingCretureT"
 android:layout_width="45dp"
 android:layout_height="45dp"></TextView>
 <EditText android:text=" "
 android:gravity="center"
 android:id="@+id/LivingCretureE" 
 android:layout_width="45dp"
 android:layout_height="45dp"></EditText>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
```

is it possiable ?

Comment: How many times do you wish to "loop"? A constant number of times, or a variable number of times determined in runtime?

Comment: constant lets assume:
    
final int NumOfRows = 10

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best option is to create a "template" tag (containing all elements you want to add in the loop) and include these elements using the `<include>` tag as many times you need.

Have a look at

- [Android Layout Trick #2: Include to Reuse](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/) and
- [Simple example of  and  usage in Android XML-layouts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732682/simple-example-of-merge-and-include-usage-in-android-xml-layouts)

Comment: thank u but
1. i find it difficult to work with when i want to work every time with another id on the same include meaning lets say i want two of this codes under uniqe name fro each one i didnt get how its possiable  
2.can i decide in a complition that this sthing run constant number of times ?