# Get a layout inflater from the ApplicationContext

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm following that guide for implementing a custom preference. http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html. In the method

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent){
   ...
}
```

The guide creates the elements programmatically and then returns the view. I'd like retrieve the layout from a xml file. But the call `getLayoutInflater()` is not accesible there how can I retrieve a layout inflater for get the view stored in the file "progressbarpreference.xml"?

I have a static reference to the application Context available if needed

Thanks

Comment: Have you registered for inflate service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourcustomviewxml, layout);
```

Got this from a question I asked: [How to pass AttributeSet to custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705144/how-to-pass-attributeset-to-custom-view) Thanks Ian!

Answer (score 18):

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

should do the trick (`ctx` is your application context in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Use the static reference, suppose if it is context.

```
rowLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.progress_bar, parent, false);
```

where progress_bar is the id of the linear layout.