# general menu for all layout android

Tags: android, menu

i have a photo sharing apps which display bottom menu in all layout i have create one but is display when i press menu key i  want menu which display when any activity start 
so how  can i create general menu for all layout and no need to press menu key for display bottom menu bar android
thanks

```
menu.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark"
      android:title="Bookmark" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_share"
      android:title="Share" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete"
      android:title="Delete" /> 


</menu>

activity.java

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: FYI, if you're looking to use `include` and `merge` with an actual menu, you'll need, instead, to inflate multiple menu XML files, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337034/include-menu-in-menu-android

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating Menu you have to make a **common custom xml layout** for your menu and include it with your all activity's layout xml file. For this you can use `<merge>` and `<include>` tag of Android XML Layout.

Look at [Layout Tricks: Merging Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

[Layout Tricks: Creating Reusable UI Components](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)

**Update:**

Now on your question, To open a Menu without pressing Menu Button, you can put this line in your `onCreate()` of Activity.

```
openOptionsMenu();
```

And to close:

```
closeOptionsMenu();
```

These both methods for Activity class, So if you are using it out-side of activity then use context of Activity and with this method.