# Showing Icons for Inner Menu Items, but not Showing Icon for Main Menu Items

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, submenu

As you can see, I am using `Icon` with each and every Menu Item, **Main** and **Inner** both the Menu Items contains *Icon*.

*Issue:* **Showing** Icons for `Inner` Menu Items, but not for `Main` Menu Items

```
1. Showing Icons for `Inner 1` and `Inner 2`

2. Not showing for `Main 1` and `Main 2`
```

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.akoscz.youtube.YouTubeActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Main 1"
        app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="Inner 1"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="Inner 2"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

    </menu>

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Main 2"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443201/android-how-to-include-a-menu-xml-inside-another-menu-xml

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was tried thing same before unfortunately not find any solution so I just go trough this possible solution.

Made a parent menu a `showAlways` it will keep your icon visible in action bar area and it will open your submenu.

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Main 1"
        app:showAsAction="showAlways">
```