# How to include layout inside layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to include layout inside layout in Android?

I am creating common layout. I want to include that layout in another page.

Comment: There is a simple usage example [in this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732682/simple-example-of-merge-and-include-usage-in-android-xml-layouts

Answer (score 232, accepted):

**Edit:** As in a comment rightly requested here some more information. Use the `include` tag

```
<include
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/yourlayout" />
```

to include the layout you want to reuse.

Check [this link](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/) out...

Comment: just a tiny detail: use android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of android:layout_width="fill_parent". 

fill_parent is deprecated.

Comment: Can I include a layout and set some of its properties via the xml, e.g. set a text string in the sublayout directly in the <include> tag?

Comment: @JohnyTex Not sure if you can do it directly in the `<include />` tag, however, you can do it using java code. see [Phileo99's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22972322/7704512) to know how to get a reference to the included layout. and then you can alter it's content.

Comment: Note, there is NO NEED to include the layout items, in, the include tag. You can just have them in the "included body" (the sub file) and it works perfectly just the same.

Answer (score 77):

Note that if you include `android:id...` into the `<include />` tag, it will override whatever id was defined inside the included layout.  For example:

```
<include
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/some_id_if_needed"
   layout="@layout/yourlayout" />
```

yourlayout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/some_other_id">
   <Button
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/button1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then you would reference this included layout in code as follows:

```
View includedLayout = findViewById(R.id.some_id_if_needed);
Button insideTheIncludedLayout = (Button)includedLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 22):

Use `<include />` tag.

```
          <include 
            android:id="@+id/some_id_if_needed"
            layout="@layout/some_layout"/>
```

Also, read [Creating Reusable UI Components](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/2.1/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) and [Merging Layouts](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/2.1/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) articles.

Comment: Both of the links does not exist any more.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/OnlineOffline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            layout="@layout/YourLayoutName" />
```

Answer (score 3):

From Official documents about **[Re-using Layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)**

> Although Android offers a variety of widgets to provide small and
>   re-usable interactive elements, you might also need to re-use larger
>   components that require a special layout. To efficiently re-use
>   complete layouts, you can use the  tag to embed another
>   layout inside the current layout.

Here is my **header.xml** file which i can reuse using **include tag**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

No I use the  tag in XML to add another layout from another XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0" >


    <include
        android:id="@+id/header_VIEW"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why put the TextView in a RelativeLayout and not as the root view?

Comment: @FlorianWalther This is an example

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But am I right that I could put the TextView as the root element or am I missing something? Because I want to reuse a ProgressBar and wonder if I have to put it into a layout.

Comment: @FlorianWalther `Because I want to reuse a ProgressBar` what problem coming?

Comment: There is no problem, it works. But all the examples I see online put the single widget into another layout and I wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

**Learn More Using this link**
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Game_logic">
    
          
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="Player " />
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    
                    android:id="@+id/text2"
                    tools:text="Player 2" />
          
            
          
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Blockquote

- Above layout you can used in other activity using

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context=".SinglePlayer">   

            <include layout="@layout/activity_game_logic"/> 
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```