# Android: how to use layouts from imported module in design mode

Tags: android, android-layout

A project contains its own MainActivity.

Some module was added into that project as an imported module.

The imported module contains a set of own Layouts and the relative "code-behind".

My question: how to add (ViewGroup with a layout) from imported .AAR module into MainActivity of the main project module during design mode?

UPD: this ref is not the same question [how to include layout inside layout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632114/how-to-include-layout-inside-layout-in-android)

I've asked about layout from inported module.. if that would be just a layout, then I wouldn't ask such question...
IMPORTED FROM AAR Library layout..

You know the answer - then show the example. too much words, mate..

Comment: What do you mean add an Activity to another? You can include layouts, but only one Activity can be used at once

Comment: If you want to use C# with Android, you can use Xamarin