# How to preview ScrollView in Android Studio preview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I have a ScrollView inside which I am using ConstraintLayout. 
Now my ConstraintLayout has a lot of views inside it and user is suppose to scroll to view them (Obviously.) But I am using android studio layout editor and I am unable to place views beneath the views that are currently at the bottom.

What is the way around this issue? Other than I type them all in XML?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632114/how-to-include-layout-inside-layout-in-android

Comment: A good way around but I don't want to chop off my layout. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In design mode, you can drag and drop views directly to the android visualization panel, but if it does not fit, also you can drop them in the Component Tree panel.

Comment: Okay. But what about the constraints? I don't think its possible to set constraints like we do in editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can set fix height to `ScrollView`, say 1000 or 2000 dp until your done with designing UI so you can add views at bottom.
Once done make it `wrap_content`