# How do I seperate my drawerlayout widget from my activity_main.xml page in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, drawerlayout

I have my drawerlayout widget on the same page as my main page and I want to separate it and create its own page. I want the main page to have its own xml page which will be located on the activity_main.xml while I want to add the drawerlayout to a separate page. How do I do this? I want to figure out how to do this in xml at the moment and not anything programmatically. This is my current code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:background="#6666ff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:scaleX="1.1"
                android:scaleY="1.0"
                android:src="@drawable/img1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"></ImageButton>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: If you need two separate activities, create a new blank activity and paste your current code in there.

Comment: which code? what are you talking about??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632114/how-to-include-layout-inside-layout Are you looking for like this?