# How to use TableLayout in one layout into another layout?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout in "action.xml" and i have another file "grid.xml" so i want to bind TableLayout from grid.xml class file so how can i do this one?

Thanks,
@nag.

Comment: just check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732682/simple-example-of-merge-and-include-usage-in-android-xml-layouts) out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can include one xml file into another xml file thru:

```
<include 
    android:id="@+id/header" 
    layout="@layout/xml_file_to_include" />
```

Comment: where you want this view to appear.....use this tag just like as other xml tags like Button, EditText etc....

Comment: when i use this include tag at starting of XML means after LinearLayout it overrides existing xml and shows included one?

Answer (score 0):

you can import the xml file into the another one like this way

```
<include  layout="@layout/mylayout" android:id="@+id/id" />
```