# What is the purpose of Android's <merge> tag in XML layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, include, code-reuse

I've read [Romain Guy's post](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) on the `<merge />` tag, but I still don't understand how it's useful. Is it a sort-of replacement of the `<Frame />` tag, or is it used like so:

```
<merge xmlns:android="....">
<LinearLayout ...>
    .
    .
    .
</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

then `<include />` the code in another file?

Answer (score 708, accepted):

`<merge/>` is useful because it can get rid of unneeded ViewGroups, i.e. layouts that are simply used to wrap other views and serve no purpose themselves.

For example, if you were to `<include/>` a layout from another file without using merge, the two files might look something like this:

layout1.xml:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <include layout="@layout/layout2"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

layout2.xml:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <TextView />
   <TextView />
</FrameLayout>
```

which is functionally equivalent to this single layout:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <FrameLayout>
      <TextView />
      <TextView />
   </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

That FrameLayout in layout2.xml may not be useful.  `<merge/>` helps get rid of it.  Here's what it looks like using merge (layout1.xml doesn't change):

layout2.xml:

```
<merge>
   <TextView />
   <TextView />
</merge>
```

This is functionally equivalent to this layout:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <TextView />
   <TextView />
</FrameLayout>
```

but since you are using `<include/>` you can reuse the layout elsewhere.  It doesn't have to be used to replace only FrameLayouts - you can use it to replace any layout that isn't adding something useful to the way your view looks/behaves.

Comment: In this example you could just make layout2.xml contain just `<TextView />`, nothing else.

Comment: True, a simple TextView could be used instead in layout2, however that then would be a completely different thing and not useful as an example in the answer to this question.

Comment: In conjunction with the <include> tag it is always useful to use <merge> tag.

Comment: @Karu: you're right, the merge tag isn't necessary in this example but that's only because there's one element in layout2. If layout2 had multiple elements, then it MUST have a root node to be valid XML and that's when the merge tag comes in handy.

Comment: So how would you specify if <merge> has vertical orientation or horizontal?  And how do you give a layout_weight?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Doesn't make any sense. If you want layout features you obviously don't use <merge>.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky if you just want to see how it will look like in android studio design editor then use tools namespace for merge layout like this:
    tools:parentTag="android.widget.LinearLayout"
    tools:orientation="horizontal"

Answer (score 384):

## The include tag

The [`<include>`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) tag lets you to divide your layout into multiple files: it helps dealing with *complex* or overlong user interface.

Let's suppose you split your complex layout using two include files as follows:

**top_level_activity.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- First include file -->
    <include layout="@layout/include1.xml" />

    <!-- Second include file -->
    <include layout="@layout/include2.xml" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you need to write `include1.xml` and `include2.xml`.

Keep in mind that the xml from the include files is simply *dumped* in your `top_level_activity` layout at rendering time (pretty much like the `#INCLUDE` macro for C).

The include files are plain jane layout xml.

**include1.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="First include"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

... and **include2.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

See? Nothing fancy. 
Note that you still have to declare the android namespace with `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`.

So the *rendered* version of  **top_level_activity.xml** is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- First include file -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="First include"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <!-- Second include file -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

In your java code, all this is transparent: `findViewById(R.id.textView1)` in your activity class returns the correct widget ( even if that widget was declared in a xml file different from the activity layout).

And the cherry on top: the **visual editor** handles the thing swimmingly. The top level layout is rendered *with* the xml included.

### The plot thickens

As an include file is a classic layout xml file, it means that it must have one top element.
So in case your file needs to include more than one widget, you would have to use a layout.

Let's say that `include1.xml` has now two `TextView`: a layout has to be declared. Let's choose  a `LinearLayout`.

**include1.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout2" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Second include"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="More text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The **top_level_activity.xml** will be rendered as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- First include file -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout2" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Second include"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="More text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

   </LinearLayout>

     <!-- Second include file -->
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*But wait the two levels of `LinearLayout` are redundant*!

Indeed, the two nested `LinearLayout` serve no purpose as the two `TextView` could be included under `layout1`for *exactly the same rendering*.

So what can we do?

## Enter the merge tag

The `<merge>` tag is just a dummy tag that provides a top level element to deal with this kind of redundancy issues.

Now **include1.xml** becomes:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Second include"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="More text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</merge>
```

and now **top_level_activity.xml** is rendered as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- First include file --> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Second include"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="More text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <!-- Second include file -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You saved one hierarchy level, avoid one useless view: Romain Guy sleeps better already.

Aren't you happier now?

Comment: Excellent description.

Comment: explains very clearly, should be chosen as the answer

Comment: Excellent, without a doubt this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: didn't understand something.. what if the outer LinearLayout is vertical for example, but the 2 textviews in the include1.xml were supposed to be horizontal? the merge in that case doesn't save their layout I wanted. What can be done about it?

Comment: @YonatanNir merge isn't what you need in your case, clearly. if you really need to flatten view hierarchy, then perhaps you can use `RelativeLayout` or draw the views manually

Comment: Answer by blazeroni was very good but this in one step ahead because of its two `TextView`s example. Thank you for brilliant explanation.

Comment: perfect, thoroughly explained

Answer (score 35):

**blazeroni** already made it pretty clear, I just want to add few points.

- `<merge>` is used for optimizing layouts.It is used for reducing unnecessary nesting.
- when a layout containing `<merge>` tag is added into another layout,the `<merge>` node is removed and its child view is added directly to the new parent.

Answer (score 12):

To have a more in-depth knowledge of what's happening, I created the following example. Have a look at the *activity_main.xml* and *content_profile.xml* files.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/content_profile" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*content_profile.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Howdy" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi there" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In here, the entire layout file when inflated looks like this.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

See that there is a LinearLayout inside the parent LinearLayout which doesn't serve any purpose and is redundant. A look at the layout through Layout Inspector tool clearly explains this.

[image]

*content_profile.xml* after updating the code to use merge instead of a ViewGroup like LinearLayout.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Howdy" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi there" />

</merge>
```

Now our layout looks like this

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here we see that the redundant LinearLayout ViewGroup is removed. Now Layout Inspector tool gives the following layout hierarchy.

[image]

**So always try to use *merge* when your parent layout can position your child layouts, or more precisely use *merge* when you understand that there is going to be a redundant view group in the hierarchy.**

Answer (score 6):

Another reason to use merge is when using custom viewgroups in ListViews or GridViews. Instead of using the viewHolder pattern in a list adapter, you can use a custom view. The custom view would inflate an xml whose root is a merge tag. 
Code for adapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     // ... typical Adapter class methods
     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        WallpaperView wallpaperView;
        if (convertView == null)
           wallpaperView = new WallpaperView(activity);
        else
            wallpaperView = (WallpaperView) convertView;

        wallpaperView.loadWallpaper(wallpapers.get(position), imageWidth);
        return wallpaperView;
    }
}
```

here is the custom viewgroup:

```
public class WallpaperView extends RelativeLayout {

    public WallpaperView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
    // ... typical constructors

    private void init(Context context) {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.wallpaper_item, this);
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        imagePlaceHolder = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLoader2);
        thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail2);
        thumbnail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }

    public void loadWallpaper(Wallpaper wallpaper, int imageWidth) {
        // ...some logic that sets the views
    }
}
```

and here is the XML:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLoader"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_loader" />

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</merge>
```

Comment: Are you implying that if you used a RelativeLayout in your XML file *and* your custom ViewGroup inherited from RelativeLayout that then there would be two RelativeLayouts, one nested in the other?

Comment: Yes, not using merge will definitely lead to an additional nested RelativeLayout. I've run into this

Answer (score 1):

Based on the android official documentation you have to use only `merge` in place of `FrameLayout` if it doesn't provide any `padding` Or `margin` etc.

**Quote:**

> Merge root frame - If a FrameLayout is the root of a layout and does
> not provide background or padding etc, it can be replaced with a merge
> tag which is slightly more efficient.

[Docs link](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout)