# why adding <merge> changes the android layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I try to include `xml_layoutA` into `xml_layoutB`.

At first I didn't know i have to add `<merge>` tag in `xml_layoutA`.

but then I added this tag and then the `xml_layoutA` started being aligned to *left* instead of to the *right* as before.

What has caused this change?

`xml_layoutA.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tooltip_layout"
    android:layout_width="262dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tip_tool_top_right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
   ...
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

vs.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tooltip_layout"
    android:layout_width="262dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tip_tool_top_right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
...

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

both case in same `xml_layoutB.xml`

in `RelativeLayout`:

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tooltipFriends"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/friendsonline_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        layout="@layout/tooltip_friends"  />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of Android's <merge> tag in XML layouts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834898/what-is-the-purpose-of-androids-merge-tag-in-xml-layouts)

Comment: no. here i have linearLayout inside relativeLayout. they should be merged anyhow

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is caused because those `include`'s parameters are ignored when using the `merge` tag.

Anyway the `merge` tag you have there is not needed and it's not doing much for you there. Basically the `merge` tag is useful when you have more view and you want those views to be included in unknown layout. For example, you have those 4 tags you want to be reused

```
<merge>
  <TextView ... />
  <TextView ... />
  <EditText ... />
  <Button ... />
</merge>
```

Then when you use this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <include layout="^^" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What you'll get is this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <TextView ... />
  <TextView ... />
  <EditText ... />
  <Button ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any parameters on the original `include` tag will be discarded, because there is no way to tell to which tag they should be added.