# Android: Define a view and its children once and reuse it anywhere

Tags: android, xml, code-reuse

I want to define the following xml once, and then reuse it any activity.  I just read that I can use styles, but the examples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) only style a single View with no children.  I know I can inflate this, but is it possible to do this purely in xml?

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/group_chat_form"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/transparent_background2" >

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/send_msg_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_background2"
    android:text="Send" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/group_chat_input_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/send_msg_button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send_msg_button"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:hint="@string/type_a_message"
    android:textColorHint="#EEEEEE"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowRadius="3"
    android:shadowDx="3"
    android:shadowDy="3"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and your problem is?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html or https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `include` tag. See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) guide.

**EDIT**

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834898/what-is-the-purpose-of-androids-merge-tag-in-xml-layouts) answer

Comment: That works for the specific example I gave, but I would like to know how to do this if the outermost view wasn't a layout. Gave you an upvote for now.

Comment: I think you are trying to refer to `merge` tag. <merge> is also explained in above link