# Merge two android layout based on XML in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I have two separate xml files in android studio.
I would like to show them in single layout. can anyone guide me to show them respectively. Also, in design tab I cannot add some button or other component why?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="net.simplifiedcoding.androidloginapp.UserProfile">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The second one is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextName" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Address"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextAddress" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Insert"
    android:onClick="insert"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewResult" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: look at this solution and take decision what you want to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/a/20874215/1206052

Answer (score 0):

You could use the include tag.
Chech [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for a complete example.
To sum up, you would create a third layout which would look like somthing like that:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/first_layout"/>
    <include layout="@layout/second_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. You mean I should make two separate xml files as first_layout.xml and second_layout.xml then write the above code?

Comment: @amirghasemi yes you need to create separate layouts then merge them into one the way mentioned in above answer

Comment: Dear friend I have made two xml files with names first_layout.xml and second_layout.xml and the above xml file. However, it just shown me first_layout.xml :( what is the problem ?

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account that the second layout is pushed off-screen when the first layout has a `match_parent` height...

Comment: then what should i have to do?