# Image Button crashes the app

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

When I add *ImageButton*s to my app (they don't have background), the app crashes.
I have following code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_main_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/home"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_main_categories"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/categories"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_main_actors"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/actors"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/twitter"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/instagram"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
```

(Whole xml is in *RelativeLayout*)... Without @null, image shows bigger than the screen. And Button fills the whole screen.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Don't do `@null` for `background`. Make it transparent so do this: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: It crashes too...

Comment: The Logcat:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 55MB until OOM

Comment: Please copy and paste your crash log here so we can see the error

Comment: For `OutOfMemoryError`, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment that the error is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, I suspect one or more of the images you are trying to load to the background take too much memory becuase they **are too big**.
The easiest solution will be to **resize the images** to a smaller size (and by this also lower your app's size). You can resize manually or use one of the solutions offered online such as :
http://resizeimage.net/

Answer (score 0):

For better result remove `wrap_content` and scale the images your self. You can shrink size of your source image.If you removed `wrap_content` also remove `background="@null"` this may help you. Please tell me how do you want to organize these ImageViews. 
You can user 'merge' tag for creating compound views , also see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834898/what-is-the-purpose-of-androids-merge-tag-in-xml-layouts).