# onCreateOptionsMenu not getting called in activity

Tags: android

onCreateOptionsMenu not getting called, i have no clue whats going on

Here is my activity

```
class BasicLayoutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_layout)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_basic_layout,menu)
        return true
    }

}
```

menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".BasicLayoutActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/like" android:title="like" app:showAsAction="always"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_insert_emoticon_black_24dp"/>

</menu>
```

theme applied

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And stackoverflow is showing me error that 'It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details :P'

Comment: remove `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` line or use `return 
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`

Comment: Its an activity, not a fragment @ColonD

Comment: not working, commented super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)

Comment: Use `override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_basic_layout,menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }`.

Comment: tried that also, not working

Comment: Is the toolbar added to the activity's view?

Comment: Figured out, include tag was not working for toolbar

Comment: removed include, its working now

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new project for you and it works as charm.

Just remove `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_layout,menu)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: found the hack, removed include. But dont know why include not working here, please take a look at my answer

Comment: No problem, I just looked your question and didn't see the `include` at the `XML` and I made a new project to see if that works.
So no problem we are here to help others so others can help us.

Comment: thanks man, can anybody confirm if it is a bug of include tag in AndroidX?

Comment: I will search for this and give you the answer.

Comment: found another interesting thing, include works if you wrap it in <merge> tag

Comment: Check this answer because has information about the `merge` `include`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093340/9560126

Comment: I know why we use <merge> and <include> , but this case was different one

Answer (score 0):

Removed include and it is working now

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/includeToolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_white"/>
```

common toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/WhiteToolbarStyle">

        <TextView
                style="@style/ToolbarTitleStyle"
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                android:text="Basic Layout"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is not working, onCreateOptionsmenu not getting called

removed include, directly added to activity layout, now its working
May be a bug in Androidx or my include file

Answer (score 0):

Change parent theme to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" or
"Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"
it seems you need "ActionBar" to hit "onCreateOptionsMenu"

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

then hide "ActionBar" as below on activity:

```
supportActionBar?.hide()
```