# <include> tag does not work when the layout to be included consists of <merge> tag. I have used the <include> tag inside a Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, mobile-application

I am using androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout in my HomeActivity.xml file where I have used the `<include>` layout="@layout/layout_top_tabs"> tag which is placing the layout at the (0,0) position of the screen (top left corner) which is not what I want. I have used `<merge>` tags inside layout_top_tabs.xml file. When I remove the `<merge>` tag, the `<include>` tag works just fine. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help!

activity_home.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Top Toolbar-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include layout="@layout/layout_top_tabs" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

layout_top_tabs.xml file:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

I am not getting any error message, but the layouts are not appearing as I have defined them in the xml files.

Comment: Please Help Someone, I'm stuck at this point and my assignment is not moving forward

Comment: What do you really want to do?

Comment: This asnser explains the merge tag:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874215/8301375

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I want to include layout_top_tabs.xml into activity_home.xml file using the `<include>` tag. But when I try to do so, the layout gets included in activity_home.xml file but at the top left corner of the screen with 0 width and 0 height. I am not able to understand the problem.