# Home button for every activity

Tags: android-widget

I am developing an android app with 9 or 10 activities, and for every activity I want to make a home button that takes the user to the main screen of the app! Some suggestions for how could i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a single XML file for that button and include it in all of your activity layouts. 
For more details: [Simple example of <merge> and <include> usage in Android XML-layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732682/simple-example-of-merge-and-include-usage-in-android-xml-layouts)