# How to make a class the parent with childs - android

Tags: android

I've got an android app, with a super-class that contains a layout that should be static for each activity, the illustration beneath shows this in a better way rather than my description

[image]

This "header" contains a `tabBar` which contains a `ImageButton`. I want this header to be static for all the activities in my app. What I tried to do, is to `extend` my other classes from this superclass. Code for the super class is beneath

```
public class MySuperClass extends Activity {
 MyHorizontalScrollView scrollView;
 View menu;
 View app;
 ImageButton btnSlide;
 boolean menuOut = false;
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 int btnWidth;

 Button testClass; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    scrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_with_list_menu, null);
    setContentView(scrollView);

    menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_menu, null);

    app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_app, null);
    ViewGroup tabBar = (ViewGroup) app.findViewById(R.id.tabBar);

    ListView listView = (ListView) app.findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView = (ListView) menu.findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems = getMenuItems();
    listView.setAdapter(new MenuCustomAdapter(this, menuItems)); 

    btnSlide = (ImageButton) tabBar.findViewById(R.id.BtnSlide);
    btnSlide.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch(event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                btnSlide.setImageResource(R.drawable.lincolor);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                btnSlide.setImageResource(R.drawable.lin);
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }


    });
    btnSlide.setOnClickListener(new ClickListenerForScrolling(scrollView, menu));

    testClass = (Button) app.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    testClass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MySuperClass.this, TestClass.class);
            startActivity(intent); 
        }


    });

    final View[] children = new View[] { menu, app };

    // Scroll to app (view[1]) when layout finished.
    int scrollToViewIdx = 1;
    scrollView.initViews(children, scrollToViewIdx, new SizeCallbackForMenu(btnSlide));
}

public ArrayList<MenuItem> getMenuItems() {
    ArrayList<MenuItem> items = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();


    MenuItem m1 = new MenuItem(R.drawable.scroll, "Show history"); 
    items.add(m1);
    MenuItem m2 = new MenuItem(R.drawable.right, "Right"); 
    items.add(m2);

    return items;
}


/**
 * Helper for examples with a HSV that should be scrolled by a menu View's width.
 */
static class ClickListenerForScrolling implements OnClickListener {
    HorizontalScrollView scrollView;
    View menu;
    ImageButton button;
    int pressed;
    int timeout;
    /**
     * Menu must NOT be out/shown to start with.
     */
    boolean menuOut = false;

    public ClickListenerForScrolling(HorizontalScrollView scrollView, View menu) {
        super();
        this.scrollView = scrollView;
        this.menu = menu; 
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = menu.getContext();

        int menuWidth = menu.getMeasuredWidth();

        // Ensure menu is visible
        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (!menuOut) {
            // Scroll to 0 to reveal menu
            int left = 0;
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(left, 0);
        } else {
            // Scroll to menuWidth so menu isn't on screen.
            int left = menuWidth;
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(left, 0);
        }
        menuOut = !menuOut;
    }


}

/**
 * Helper that remembers the width of the 'slide' button, so that the 'slide' button remains in view, even when the menu is
 * showing.
 */
static class SizeCallbackForMenu implements SizeCallback {
    int btnWidth;
    View btnSlide;

    public SizeCallbackForMenu(View btnSlide) {
        super();
        this.btnSlide = btnSlide;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        btnWidth = btnSlide.getMeasuredWidth();
        System.out.println("btnWidth=" + btnWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void getViewSize(int idx, int w, int h, int[] dims) {
        dims[0] = w;
        dims[1] = h;
        final int menuIdx = 0;
        if (idx == menuIdx) {
            dims[0] = w - btnWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And a test class, which extends this superclass.

```
public class TestClass extends MySuperClass {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

}
```

}

Again how can I make the `tabBar` static for each activity?

Comment: Define your header in xml, and then include it in every page you use. That'd be my choice

Comment: use http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this in an Activity-scope. The layout are independent from your Acitvity (well, until you bind them).

The solution to your problem, may be in using a common header layout, kept in a xml file under your layout folder, something like this:

header.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/red"
    ... />
```

And include them in your layouts, using the include tag:

my_activity_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ....
    .... >

    <include layout="@layout/header.xml" android:id="@+id/header" />

    <!-- Countinue your layout .... -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This solution will work on the layout side, but not the OnClickListeners from the inherited class.

Comment: Why not? You just have to assign id's for your Views, and get them by calling findViewById in every activity you need them. Then assign the listeners normally.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a TabHost right. by click on each tab you can launch separate activity

http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/tablayouttabhost-tutorial-for-android-reusing-layout/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that is possible. I will post an alternative solution, which requires a little bit of more code but works, and is a best practice, so if nothing comes up this is the best alternative, probably the only one.

When you are trying to use a certain layout again and again, like the tab bar that you are mentioning, there is the `<merge>` and `<include>` functionality in the layout. The basic idea is that you make a `layout.xml` file that you want to include in other layouts.

This post gives a very good example of how to use it. [Simple example of <merge> and <include> usage in Android XML-layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732682/simple-example-of-merge-and-include-usage-in-android-xml-layouts)