# Sharing some XML between layouts

Tags: android

I want to make something that is a vertical `LinearLayout` on the phone version of an app, a horizontal one for tablets.

The view in question is located inside a large XML file that specifies the entire view.

The *naive* way to do this is to just copy and paste the file from `res/layout` to `res/layout-sw600dp`. I did this and it works. However this means I know have to maintain **two** files if I want to make other UX changes. This is inefficient.

What is the easiest way to abstract away the LinearLayout in question?

I have looked at [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#basic) but it goes farther than I would like to go. I do not want to have to make code changes for this, it should be self-contained in XML changes.

Comment: Not sure I completely understood your question, however you can create a base layout and create a container to be included in your sw600dp and layout folders. Check http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: @fedepaol Aha! That's exactly what I was searching for. Thanks. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: I think you want to use the "include" feature.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732682/simple-example-of-merge-and-include-usage-in-android-xml-layouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse layouts using < include > and < merge> tags.

Doing that, you can have different containers in sw600dp and layout folders including the same common layout.

Official doc [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)