# usage of findviewbyid in preferenceactivity

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I have a preference screen and i am specifying a layout resource using the `android:layout` attribute. In the preference activity i am using/inflating the preference using `addPreferencesFromResource` from `onCreate` method. Inside the layout i have few textviews and buttons.

The problem is i am unable to find any of the textviews, checkboxes and buttons using `findViewById` method ! Every result for `findViewById` returns null.

**EDIT**:

I need to attach a listener to the checkbox.

Can anyone please help me over here ?

**EDIT 2**:

**1) preference_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="33dp"
    android:id="@+id/preference_header_switch_item_responder_layout"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" >

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/switchWidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**2) preference screen**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Preference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="auto_responder_key"
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/preference_layout"
        android:title="@string/auto_responder">
    </Preference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**3)Preference Activity onCreate:**

**EDIT 3:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(HEADERS_KEY))
        {
            headers = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(HEADERS_KEY);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        applicationContext = getApplicationContext();

        setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
//      setContentView(getListView());
        headerCompound = findViewById(R.id.switchWidget);
        headerCompoundEmail = findViewById(R.id.switchWidgetEmail);
    }
```

and

```
private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen()
    {
        if (!isSimplePreferences(this))
        {
            return;
        }

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.responder_generic);

    PreferenceCategory fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);

        fakeHeader.setLayoutResource(R.layout.place_holder_auto_reply_header);

        getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.auto_reply_sms_call_check_box_preference);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.auto_reply_preferences);

        Preference smsTemplatePreference = findPreference(SMS_TEMPLATE_KEY);
        if(smsTemplatePreference != null)
        {
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(smsTemplatePreference);
        }

        Preference customTemplatePreference = findPreference(SMS_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_KEY);
        if(customTemplatePreference != null)
        {
            customTemplatePreference.setEnabled(false);
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(customTemplatePreference);
            getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(customTemplatePreference);
        }

        // Add 'email' preferences, and a corresponding header.

        // Add 'email header' preferences.
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.email_enable_check);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.email_preferences);

        Preference passwordPreference = findPreference(EMAIL_PWD_KEY);

        if(passwordPreference != null)
        {
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(passwordPreference);
            // the advanced version of SMS template
        }

        Preference customPasswordPreference = findPreference(EMAIL_CUSTOM_PWD_KEY);
        if(customPasswordPreference != null)
        {
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(customPasswordPreference);
            getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(customPasswordPreference);
        }

        // Add 'network' preferences, and a corresponding header.
        fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
        fakeHeader.setLayoutResource(R.layout.place_holder_network_header);

        getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.network_preferences_check_box);

        // Add 'misc' preferences, and a corresponding header.
        fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
        fakeHeader.setLayoutResource(R.layout.place_holder_misc_header);

        getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.misc_preferences);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.misc_reject_ignore_check_box_preferences);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/Switch/CheckBox preferences to
        // their values. When their values change, their summaries are updated
        // to reflect the new value, per the Android Design guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(AUTO_REPLY_SMS_KEY));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(AUTO_REPLY_CALL_KEY));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(DATA_NETWORK_KEY));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(WIFI_KEY));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(PASSCODE_KEY));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(EMAIL_USR_KEY));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(EMAIL_INT_KEY));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(AUTO_RESPONDER_KEY));
}
```

I tried the above code in `onPostCreate` as well but still the value returned is null.

I want to find checkboxes for responder_generic.xml and email_preferences.xml. Is there a way to find and add listeners to them ?

Thanks,
Adithya

Comment: can you post what have you tried

Comment: i have added my code.

Comment: pls post your full java code

Comment: added entire code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What i did was create a custom preference and it worked. I simply extended `Preference` class and inflated the layout provided in the layout/%MY_LAYOUT%.xml. The listeners were being called as well which is what i wanted to achieve.

This solution was nowhere i believe, hence, i adding this to community Wiki.

**Note** : if there is a single preference being added then [single preference solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697233/how-to-add-a-button-to-preferencescreen) should suffice. I am adding multiple preferences on screen (in my case 2), i implemented custom preferences.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have asked it appears that you are not able to get any view when you are using

```
findViewById()
```

so one possible reason for this behavior could be that you may not have called

```
 setContentView(R.id.yourlayout);
```

check this out in your code...

Comment: actually,there are various preferences i am loading on the activity and couple of them have layouts, hence, i didn't use setContentView for a particular layout. Are you suggesting to setContentView for both the layouts one after the other ? will that work ? I will try it though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to put directly a RadioGroup in the PreferenceScreen. I was trying to set the checked RadioButton when creating the Activity (e.g. restoring the value of a boolean from sharedpreferences) but i wasn't able to findViewById or similiar from the OnCreate method.
Here's my (ugly but working) solution:
I extended the RadioButton class:

```
public class RadioButtonSettings extends RadioButton {
public RadioButtonSettings(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    boolean isLocal = context.getSharedPreferences("",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("local",true);
    switch(getId()){
        case R.id.radio_in:
            if(isLocal)
                setChecked(true);
            break;
        case R.id.radio_out:
            if(!isLocal)
                setChecked(true);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}}
```

then put somewhere in your preferences.xml file (loaded by the PreferenceActivity):

```
<PreferenceCategory
android:title="CATEGORY EXAMPLE">
<Preference android:layout="@xml/category_one"
    android:selectable="false"
    android:key="radiobuttons">
</Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

and finally create another file in the res/xml directory (named category_one.xml) and put:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <your.package.RadioButtonSettings
        tools:context="your.package.SettingsActivity"
        android:id="@+id/radio_in"
        android:text="@string/radioIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </your.package.RadioButtonSettings>
    <your.package.RadioButtonSettings
        tools:context="your.package.SettingsActivity"
        android:id="@+id/radio_out"
        android:text="@string/radioOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </your.package.RadioButtonSettings>
</RadioGroup>
```

You could also use the android:onClick="" option from the xml file to get the OnClickListener.
In the specific case it was a simple check for a boolean "local" (radiobutton "in" and radiobutton "out"). You can also obviously override other classic methods. I think maybe it's a better solution than extending the entire Preference class. Hoping it will help someone.