# What is the difference between include tag and merge tag in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, merge, include

I just need someone to tell me if I understood correctly when to use `<include>` and when `<merge>`.

So, I make a header layout which I want to include into some other XML layout:

it is a my merge sample for adding the two views

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
           <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="Header text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I include it into some other XML this way (which is pretty basic):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
               <include android:id="@+id/header" layout="@layout/top"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will work well, no issue about it. But in order to optimize the code, I have to use `<merge>` in the layout which gets included. So the top layout should not have a tag `<LinearLayout>` but it must look like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:text="Header text" />
</merge>
```

Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Also another for examples : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732682/simple-example-of-merge-and-include-usage-in-android-xml-layouts?rq=1

Comment: And yes you understood Correctly 100%.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check This [Difference between include and merge](https://alltechsolution.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/difference-between-merge-includeand-tag-in-android/)